# Charts.js Y-Axis whole Numbers

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a Charts.js Bar-Chart with whole Numbers, like 1,2,3,4,5 - I will never have 1.5 , 2.7 etc.
But the Charts shows all the decimal Numbers, like in the Screenshot.
I want that the Chart only shows whole number. I can't find a Solution for this. Can you help me?

[Screenshot of my Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiyMM.png)

This is my Configuration:

```
type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: departmentLabels,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Staff',
      backgroundColor: color(window.chartColors.grey).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
      borderColor: window.chartColors.black,
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: departmentCount
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Usage by Department'
    },
  }
```

Comment: what do you mean by comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this code inside the `option` section

```
 scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          callback: function(value) {if (value % 1 === 0) {return value;}}
        }
      }]
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `stepSize` property:

```
scales: {
  yAxes: [{
    ticks: {
      stepSize: 1
    }
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 8):

A better way to do it which allows for scaling is to use the `precision` property:

```
scales: {
    y: {
        ticks: {
            precision: 0
        }
    }
}
```

This way, if you add a 100 or something, it can increase the step size if needed. It just won't even lower it below 1.